React Project is gettimg a error initializing openkit for Telemetry error, but project doesnt use Next.js
Currently trying to build a react project and I am getting a "Error initializing open kit for Telemetry". Upon research, I found it's used for Next.js but the project I am working doesn't use Next.js.
Is there a possibility that a dependency is using Telemetry, or could it be something else? How do I get rid of it?
